# MS-Project 2010: Task end-date seems to be calcuated incorrectly

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I am using MS-Project 2010 and have noticed something peculiar in how "end-date" of the task is dislayed. I obeserve the following behavior:
 1. I set the task to start on Monday.
 2. I set the duration for 5 days.
Strictly speaking my task should finish at the end of the working day on Friday, yet MS Project shows the completion date as the following Monday. Linking next task to this one, sets the start date correctly to the following Monday.

Any advise, on how to interpret this behavior and whether it is possible to show the completion of the task as Friday in my example?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: format the start date to show the time, as well.  it may show a start time in the evening, thus counting the first day as tuesday.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. That did the trick. Somehow my calendar got screwed. Start time became 9am instead of 8am and therefore extra hour got carried out to Monday.

Comment: @DavidEspina You should make your comment an answer, perhaps with a screenshot or a small bit of elaboration.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that you had to enter the number of days in a month.  It can only be set once - the default is 20 working days.  if you do not use "month" as a duration the setting has no effect.  The number of working hours in the calendar needs to match the working time definition.  Your "day" is 8 hours, your week is 48.  You need to modify the working time to allow 6 working days per week.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a huge inherited project. The only work around so far, is to manually change the start date to what your calendar start time is. For example- my calendar is set accurately. However some task show finish at 2:34pm instead of 5pm. so I have to manually change them to 5pm. I agree with John Thomas. This is a flaw in MS Project.

Comment: You mention your calendar is set accurately - how about the number of hours in a day?  What is the calendar for your project.  With all respect - if the project is set up properly Project excels at calculating schedules.  If you'd like to add more details - I'm sure someone will be happy to assist.  Manually changing start dates and finish dates is NOT the way to fix the schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

As David notes, change your date format to show date/time.  **File > Options, General** under **Project View**.

You may have a mis-match between the number of working hours in your calendar and the definition of "day".  Are you working with a calendar that has less than 8 working hours per day?  If so, you need to modify the Calendar options to match.  For example - if you have altered your calendar to a 7.5 hour day - the calendar options need to match.

When you enter "5 days" Project interprets that as 40 working hours.  If you calendar only allows 7.5 working hours per day - it will run in to Monday.

Comment: Julie, answer my question regarding S curves.  Need your help!